# Handling logged in users in react native in the StackNavigator

Tags: react-native

I have code that looks like this:

```
function RootNavigator() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false)

  isUserLoggedIn().then((someBoolean) => {
    setIsLoggedIn(someBoolean)
  })
  
    console.log("LOGEED IN STSTE:", isLoggedIn)
   return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      {isLoggedIn || <Stack.Screen name="Root" component={WelcomeScreen} />}
      {isLoggedIn && <Stack.Screen name="InvestorProfileQuiz" component={InvestorProfileQuizScreen} />}
      {isLoggedIn || <Stack.Screen name="AppTour" component={AppTourScreen} />}
      {isLoggedIn || <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />}
      {isLoggedIn || <Stack.Screen name="NotFound" component={NotFoundScreen} options={{ title: 'Oops!' }} />}
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

So the problem is that on render, the `isLoggedIn` piece of state is false and then the first page `WelcomeScreen` renders. The screen flickers in, then the `isLoggedIn` is changed to true, and then the `InvestorProfileQuiz` correctly renders. How do I ensure that the async/await method `isUserLoggedIn()` resolves before rendering the StackNavigtor children?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I usually handle the logged in and logged out state.

```
function RootNavigator() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  // Passing an empty array as second argument
  // makes useEffect behave like componentDidMount
  useEffect(() => {
    
    // Wrap logic in the async init function
    // since the useEffect callback can't be async
    async function init() {
      const someBoolean = await isUserLoggedIn();
      setIsLoggedIn(someBoolean);
    }
    init();
  }, []);

  // Return null or your logged out screen component here.
  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Root" component={WelcomeScreen} />}
      <Stack.Screen
        name="InvestorProfileQuiz"
        component={InvestorProfileQuizScreen}
      />
      <Stack.Screen name="AppTour" component={AppTourScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />(
      <Stack.Screen
        name="NotFound"
        component={NotFoundScreen}
        options={{title: 'Oops!'}}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```